# Access URL in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a variable for the url location, and change text depending on the input. For example, for bill.google.com, the value of the variable would be bill. For example.google.com, the value of the variable would be example. I don't know how to access the text in the url. Help?

Comment: You need to parse [window.location.hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Answer (score 2):

```
location.hostname.split('.')[0]
```

Will get you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: What if it's http://foo.bar.baz.com

Comment: Great question. Would love to see an answer with some more use cases taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

How to access the text in the URL

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: What? That's not at all what he asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

```
window.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at window.location?

- **location.hostname** returns the domain name of the web host
- **location.pathname** returns the path and filename of the current page
- **location.port** returns the port of the web host (80 or 443)
- **location.protocol** returns the web protocol used (http:// or https://)

See more at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would get you close. *note*: not tested much.

```
 var _url = location.hostname;
 var _reg = /(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(?:www\.)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/i;
 var result = _url.match(_reg);
 console.log(result);
```